# Find convergence a.s and in probability of $X_n$ if $P(X_n = 0) = \frac{1}{2n^\lambda}$ and $P(X_n = 2) = 1 - P(X_n=0)$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Given $\lambda > 0$ I want to find the convergence a.s and the convergence in probability of $X_n$ if $P(X_n = 0) = \frac{1}{2n^\lambda}$ and $P(X_n = 2) = 1 - P(X_n=0)$.

For the convergence a.s my guess is that we can use the Borel-Cantelli lemma for different values of $\lambda$. Also $\lim_{n\to\infty}P(X_n=0) = 0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}P(X_n=2) = 1$ regardless of the value $\lambda$ takes.

Can I use this to find the convergence in probability somehow?

Comment: You have been writing $X$ for $X_n$ throughout.

Comment: $P(|X_n-2|>\epsilon)=P(X_n=0)=\frac1 {2n^{\lambda}} \to 0$ so $X_n \to 2$ in probability.

Comment: Yes, the two Borel-Cantelli lemmas can be used for convergence a.s.
For convergence in probability, just use the definition of convergence in probability.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Don't you need independence to determine when exactly we have a.s. convergence?

Comment: Independence is needed for the "second" Borel-Cantelli lemma, not the first.

Comment: So if $\lambda > 1$ then by the first Borel-Cantelli lemma $X_n$ converges a.s to $2$ and if $\lambda \leq 1$ we need $X_n$ to be independent to be able to use the second lemma?